# Print in swift doesn't terminate by \n

Tags: ios, swift, printing, bluetooth

I am working with Bluetooth on iOS 9 with Xcode 7, swift 2.

I receive a value using Bluetooth and I would like to print it on debug.

Here is my code :

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {

    IncomingBLE = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
    print(IncomingBLE, separator: ";", terminator: "\n")
    print("") }
```

and in my debug I got this :

```
Humidity50.00Temp30.00BatLevel80
Humidity
50.00Temp30.00BatLevel80Humidity50.00Temp
30.00
BatLevel80Humidity50.00
```

sometimes line return appear but often it is not here. What is the reason ?

Comment: Are these all happening on the same thread?

Comment: Yes, i am not using multitask but i'll check if my data don't come to fast over Bluetooth

Comment: I think the problem is that you have `'\n'` but should have `\\n`

Comment: Why and where should have \\n ?

Comment: The delegate method is called asynchronously as data is received, so if data is arriving rapidly you will get intertwined output.  You can dispatch your print statements onto a serial-dispatch queue to resolve this.  \\n won't help - it will just print the literal "\n" rather than a new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` is called asynchronously. when the value is updated rapidly it is possible for the data to get intertwined on the console.  You can try dispatching your print on the main queue as this is a serial dispatch queue;

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {

    IncomingBLE = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        print(IncomingBLE, separator: ";", terminator: "\n")
    }
 }
```

*Update*

For debugging purposes, the `NSLog` statement can be more reliable;

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {

    IncomingBLE = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        NSLog(IncomingBLE.description)
    }
}
```

It may even work without the `dispatch_async`

Comment: It's not working, i got something like that now : `30.00BatLevel80Humidity50.00Temp30.00BatLevel80Humidity50.00Temp30.00BatLevel80Humidity50.00Temp30.00BatLevel80Humidity50.00Temp30.00BatLevel80Humidity50.00Temp30.00BatLevel80Humidity50.00Temp30.00BatLevel80Humidity50.00Temp30.00Bat`
With no "\n" :(

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure.  You can try the simpler `print(IncomingBLE)`

Comment: Try `NSLog(IncomingBLE.description)`.  I can't reproduce your problem exactly because I don't have the BLE peripheral but I can see in the playground that the print statement generates a \n

Comment: It's working : `2016-02-01 01:18:20.178 Echo on the Wing[1494:764595] 30.00
2016-02-01 01:18:20.684 Echo on the Wing[1494:764595] BatLevel
2016-02-01 01:18:21.165 Echo on the Wing[1494:764595] 80
2016-02-01 01:18:23.745 Echo on the Wing[1494:764595] Humidity
2016-02-01 01:18:24.225 Echo on the Wing[1494:764595] 50.00
2016-02-01 01:18:24.735 Echo on the Wing[1494:764595] Temp
2016-02-01 01:18:25.245 Echo on the Wing[1494:764595] 30.00
2016-02-01 01:18:25.725 Echo on the Wing[1494:764595] BatLevel`
that's mean my NSString is BatLevel for exemple right ?

Comment: Yes, print() generate \n by default, but not here and i don't know why, it's my question ;)

Comment: I think print() is mainly for use in Playgrounds.  I wouldn't use it in an app- use NSLog

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway, i wanted just know if my NSString was good, and it's appear good :)